# How to get count in first activity for shopping cart?

Tags: android, android-studio, ormlite

```
@EBean
public class CartDB {

@OrmLiteDao(helper = DatabaseHelper.class, model = Cart.class)
CartDao cartDao;

public Cart getCart() {
    return cartDao.getCart()}

public String count(){
    long count =0;
    try {
        count= cartDao.countOf();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return count+"";
  }
```

In my second Activity onCreate() I call Count method

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

Log.e("Count",cartDB.count()+"");
}
```

than count method return data ,
but In my first activity onCreate() I call count method

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_layout);
            Log.e("Count",cartDB.count()+"");
    }
```

**nullpointer exeption and my app crashes**

Note: retrieving data from Sqlite database

Comment: Please show your logcat @Payal.Please follow the answer below.

Comment: 04-22 15:00:44.453 567-567/com.gems.anychinese E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gems.anychinese/com.gems.anychinese.DashBoardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The null pointer exception is because you have not initialized your Java Class CardDB in your Activity;

Please make an instance of CartDB:

```
CartDB mycart;
```

then in your Activity's onCreate method initialize it properly:

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_layout);
mycart=new CartDB();

}
```

Comment: i initialize cardDb above onCreate()

Comment: Please show your full logcat in your question.@Payel.So that we can actually debug where is the problem.

Comment: yes I use annotation in my app so initialisation of mycart is                                                                          @Bean CartDB cartDb;